# Troubleshoot noise in audio mixer circuit

Tags: noise, sound, troubleshooting

I have a Soundcraft EPM6 sound mixer. Recently I noticed a click noise in the right channel of a stereo input. The click seems to happen at each period of the sound wave (I feed a 2 Hz signal, and was able to count two clicks per second.) Each channel has these components:

| control | What I have done |
| --- | --- |
| gain | The noise is not affected by the position of this knob |
| high/low eq | The noise does get affected by the eq. |
| aux1/2 | When I route sound to these output, the noise is present |
| balance | The noise is only present in the right channel |
| pre-fader level switch | The noise remains if I monitor the sound pre-fader |
| mute | Kills the noise |
| fader | It does affect the level of the noise |

After troubleshooting to discover at which point of the sound path the noise is introduced, I think it is generated before the eq. This area corresponds to the lower left corner in the schematic presented below.

[image: Soundcraft EPM6 stereo input circuit diagram]

My knowledge in electronics is pretty basic. I get what a potentiometer and a couple of other components are, but I don't know how capacitors, resistors, and the opamps work together to modify the signal.

What steps should I follow from this point, to find out the problem, and eventually fix it?

Comment: The only components that are prone to fail are ICs and aluminium electrolytic caps. And as IC1400A and IC1400B are one IC, I would try and exchange C1405 for a fresh one.

Comment: By C1405, do you mean IC1400, or the pot P1405?

Comment: No, I mean the aluminium electrolytic cap C1405. Because if IC1400 was at failure, it's likely that both channels would show the problem.

Comment: true true, thanks. I will try it and update you with the results. (the annoying part is to take apart more than 120 knobs, screws and nuts...)

Answer (score 2):

I’m going to go out on a limb and say replace IC1400.  The gain control is in the feedback loop and so may not affect the amplitude of the click, and it’s unlikely that any failure mode of the passive components would result in crossover distortion.  Replacing an IC somewhat speculatively will take a few minutes and cost little, and may well resolve the problem without further ado.  Tip: If this is a DIL package device mounted through-hole then it may be easiest to snip the pins and remove them one by one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. They are SMD. Do you know how/where I could get a couple of IC, without having to buy 1000 at the time?

Comment: You can get TL072 for a buck apiece at Digikey or Mouser, but you could first test the theory by swapping IC1400 and IC1401. If the symptom doesn't change then it's not a bad opamp.

Comment: True but it may be difficult to tell the difference as there’s not a great deal of gain between the two locations.

Comment: True but OP seems to believe the problem can be be pinpointed to "before the EQ", so can discern which location is the problem. Personally, I think it at least as likely to be a loose wire or bad solder joint than a bad component.

Comment: can a bad capacitor produce this kind of problems?

Comment: @onlycparra it would be difficult to say that a bad cap couldn’t cause this but I’ve never seen a failure mode that results in crossover distortion.